# Install database_gap in sagemath

Tags: sage

I'm using sageMath on windows and i need to install the GAP package to work with 'transitive groups'. But i've tried every tip on the internet and nothing seems to work.
Can you please detail the steps for me? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Have you tried doing `sage -i database_gap` from the command line inside the virtual machine?  However, I'm not an expert on the virtualization options on Windows.